# How do I create a vector?

Tags: r, vector, matrix

I want the data that is generated as a vector or matrix in R, what should I do?

```
> for(i in  1:100)  { if(i%%5==0 && i%%8==5)  print(i) } 
[1] 5 
[1] 45 
[1] 85
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're just trying to do this:

```
x <- 1:100
x[x %% 5 == 0 & x %% 8 == 5]
# [1]  5 45 85
```

Comment: so thanks:)      if the out puts don't change in the loop range، what i do ?

Comment: @user2607593, sorry, I don't understand that follow-up question at all.

Comment: perhaps ???? the OP wants to assign the result to another vector ???

Comment: @BenBolker, that would be pretty amusing/amazing if that's where they're stuck!